# How to memorize one element from summary(VAR((b, p = 3, type = "const")) in R?

Tags: r, summary

After running `summary(VAR((b, p = 3, type = "const"))`, I get the result shown at the end of this question.

I would like to memorize not all results, but only one value: `diff_gov.l3  **0.37446** (Estimate)`.

I suppose that my code should start with `summary(VAR((b, p = 3, type = "const"))$SOMETHING`, but I do not know how to define the position of `diff_gov.l3` in column `Estimate` (**0.37446**).

Do you have any suggestion how can I define the position of the value I need (`summary(VAR((b, p = 3, type = "const"))$SOMETHING`) or is there a way to see the position of every element in the result of `summary()` code?

RESULT:

```
summary(VAR(b, p = 3, type = "const"))

VAR Estimation Results:
========================= 
Endogenous variables: diff_gov, diff_hh 
Deterministic variables: const 
Sample size: 47 
Log Likelihood: 64.057 
Roots of the characteristic polynomial:
0.7848 0.7848 0.7722 0.693 0.693 0.5438
Call:
VAR(y = b, p = 3, type = "const")


Estimation results for equation diff_gov: 
========================================= 
diff_gov = diff_gov.l1 + diff_hh.l1 + diff_gov.l2 + diff_hh.l2 + diff_gov.l3 + diff_hh.l3 + const 

            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
diff_gov.l1  0.18760    0.15514   1.209  0.23366   
diff_hh.l1   0.06080    0.04760   1.277  0.20889   
diff_gov.l2 -0.35682    0.19484  -1.831  0.07450 . 
diff_hh.l2   0.14308    0.04650   3.077  0.00376 **
diff_gov.l3  0.37446    0.18893   1.982  0.05438 . 
diff_hh.l3   0.02682    0.05061   0.530  0.59910   
const        0.02261    0.02707   0.835  0.40849   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


Residual standard error: 0.07446 on 40 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-Squared: 0.3626,     Adjusted R-squared: 0.267 
F-statistic: 3.792 on 6 and 40 DF,  p-value: 0.004396 


Estimation results for equation diff_hh: 
======================================== 
diff_hh = diff_gov.l1 + diff_hh.l1 + diff_gov.l2 + diff_hh.l2 + diff_gov.l3 + diff_hh.l3 + const 

             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
diff_gov.l1  1.403165   0.501766   2.796   0.0079 **
diff_hh.l1   0.007256   0.153957   0.047   0.9626   
diff_gov.l2 -1.548307   0.630178  -2.457   0.0184 * 
diff_hh.l2   0.057511   0.150394   0.382   0.7042   
diff_gov.l3  1.294856   0.611078   2.119   0.0404 * 
diff_hh.l3  -0.238964   0.163701  -1.460   0.1522   
const        0.212912   0.087541   2.432   0.0196 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


Residual standard error: 0.2408 on 40 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-Squared: 0.2527,     Adjusted R-squared: 0.1406 
F-statistic: 2.254 on 6 and 40 DF,  p-value: 0.05745 



Covariance matrix of residuals:
         diff_gov  diff_hh
diff_gov 0.005544 0.003397
diff_hh  0.003397 0.057993

Correlation matrix of residuals:
         diff_gov diff_hh
diff_gov   1.0000  0.1894
diff_hh    0.1894  1.0000
```

Comment: You should include `library(vars)` in your code. It's hard for us to know where `VAR` comes from otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're interested in the structure of an object, so that you can extract particular elements, you can use `str(x)`, e.g. `str(summary(VAR(b, p = 3, type = "const")))`.

For `varest` objects produced by `vars::VAR`, you can access the coefficients, p-values, etc. for a particular equation by accessing `summary(m)$varresult$eq$coefficients`, where `m` is the `varest` object, and `eq` is the variable of interest (`diff_gov` in your case).

Here's an example:

```
library(vars)
data(Canada)
m <- VAR(Canada, p = 2, type = "none")
summary(m)$varresult$e$coefficients

#            Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
# e.l1     1.62046761 0.15483879 10.4655148 3.011899e-16
# prod.l1  0.17973134 0.06295812  2.8547760 5.584192e-03
# rw.l1   -0.04425592 0.05652496 -0.7829448 4.361581e-01
# U.l1     0.11310425 0.19947288  0.5670157 5.724195e-01
# e.l2    -0.64815156 0.15207587 -4.2620276 5.893211e-05
# prod.l2 -0.11683270 0.06797209 -1.7188334 8.982575e-02
# rw.l2    0.04475537 0.05472427  0.8178341 4.160775e-01
# U.l2    -0.06581206 0.19724901 -0.3336496 7.395876e-01
```

The resulting object is a matrix that can be subsetted normally. For example, to extract the estimate associated with `rw.l1`, you can use:

```
summary(m)$varresult$e$coefficients['rw.l1', 'Estimate']

[1] -0.04425592
```

So, in your case, you want something like this:

```
m <- VAR(b, p = 3, type = "const")
summary(m)$varresult$diff_gov$coefficients['diff_gov.l3', 'Estimate']
```

Comment: str(x) solved all my problems. Thank you for editing my question and instant reply.